# How do i redirect after my mail has been send(wp_mail)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am wondering how to redirect after my mail has been send I tried doing it with javascript, I also tried it with `header("Location: "www.google.com"")` but it wont work and I dont know how to solve this. I really hope someone could help me. this is my code:

```
<script>
        var text;
        function show(param_div_id,button) {    
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['reset'])) {
                $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                $result = str_ireplace("undefined" , "" , $_POST["ll"][0]);
                $email = $_POST["ll"][1];
                wp_mail( "email@hotmail.com", "email","Dear, <br><br>".
                    "From test filled in by " .$email. " this came out: <br><br>".
                    $result. "<br><br> Greetings, <br> website.nl"
                    ,$headers); 
            }
            ?>document.getElementById('main_place').innerHTML = document.getElementById(param_div_id).innerHTML;
            text = text + " " + button;
            var ll=document.getElementById('ll');
            ll.value=text;
            console.log(button)
        }
    </script>
    <?php

}
```

I would really like it to go to a thank you page after sending the email.

Comment: where did you try and put the javascript redirect?

Comment: after the wp_mail and after the if(isset($_POST['reset']))

Comment: and you can usee wp_redirect( '"/thank-you-page", int $status = 302 ) https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Comment: before the wp_mail it is going to that page, but after the wp_mail it just refreshes the page im already on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP can't modify the headers once output has started, including whitespace. You can use javascript to redirect the page. You could have your if statement echo the javascript `window.location.href='www.stackoverflow.com'`

```
if(isset($_POST['reset'])) {
                $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                $result = str_ireplace("undefined" , "" , $_POST["ll"][0]);
                $email = $_POST["ll"][1];
                wp_mail( "email@hotmail.com", "email","Dear, <br><br>".
                    "From test filled in by " .$email. " this came out: <br><br>".
                    $result. "<br><br> Greetings, <br> website.nl"
                    ,$headers);
                echo 'window.location.href="www.stackoverflow.com";';
            }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you but I tried this and its just not redirecting, it seems like it is ending the code after the mail and i cannot put anything after that.

Comment: I had an error in the code, php would have failed, I added double quotes inside the echo statement, and needed the semicolon at the end, try that

Comment: Its still not redirecting.

Comment: i found the error if I write it like this : echo 'window.location.href="www.stackoverflow.com";'; it is working